# How to set FAB in front of bottom app bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, floating-action-button, material-components-android

How can I bring the floating action button in front of the bottom app bar?
In other words, how to set the bottom app bar to fill the entire row behind the fab?

From this:
[image]

To this:
[image]

*Images via [medium.com](https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/implementing-bottomappbar-material-components-for-android-f490c4a01708)*

According to [this tutorial](https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/implementing-bottomappbar-material-components-for-android-f490c4a01708) there should be an attribute named `fabCradleDiameter` but in reality there is no such attribute for this component.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Use a FrameLayout or one of it's descendants to house your FAB.

Comment: Please paste your current code to see what have you tried so far..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the official [`BottomAppBar`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomAppBar.md) and use the:

- **`fabCradleMargin`** attribute.
  It increases or decreases the distance between the `FloatingActionButton` and the `BottomAppBar`
- **`fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius`** attribute. It specifies the roundness of the corner around the cutout

Use:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bar"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:fabCradleMargin="0dp"
    app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="0dp"
    ... />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bar"
    .../>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there isn't an attribute named `fabCradleDiameter`,  its [fabCradleMargin](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/R.attr#fabCradleMargin)

and make sure the version is after:

```
com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha3
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this it worked for me.. may work for you as well.

```
<android.support.design.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center"
        app:fabCradleMargin="0dp"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:hideOnScroll="true"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_black_24dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_red_24dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Key is to use new material theme. Also your container layout should be coordinator layout. Use below code to change your layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!-- Other components and views -->

  <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
      android:id="@+id/bar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"      //Material style. 
      app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_24"/>

  <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
      android:id="@+id/fab"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_anchor="@id/bar"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I think as soon as you read the first sentence of my question, you rushed to put an answer here. Please read the question carefully.