# How to change FAB position from inset to overlap with BottomAppBar?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, floating-action-button, android-coordinatorlayout

Left side AppBar shows the current design, I want to change it to right side design

[image]

How to change FAB position from  inset to overlap  with `BottomAppBar`?

Comment: Decreasing radius and margins on the FAB like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57664126/6287910) is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can't use the `app:layout_anchor` attribute so that the `FAB` can intersect with the `BottomNavigationView` without a cutout.

You can use `ConstraintLayout` attributes to center the FAB on the top edge of the `BottomNavView`

And either use a `0dp` elevation on the `BottomNavBar` or a great elevation on the FAB so that the `FAB` can be laid on top of it.

Fore more info please [check the documentation](https://material.io/components/app-bars-bottom).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_button"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/purple_200"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/navigation"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/navigation"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/navigation"
        app:elevation="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/navigation"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_star_24"
        app:tint="@color/white" />


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]